# how between sql in 2 column

Tags: sql, request

I, i search if I can reserve date, this is my table timestamps:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
| idReserver | demandeur | reserverAvecQui | reserverWhy    | saisieQuant | reserverDate | reserverStartH | reserverEndH | reserverOk |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
|          1 | test.fr  | anonyme         | Je ne sais pas |  1524167863 |   1524175200 |     1524222000 |   1524240000 |       NULL |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

I try this request SQL:

this is my request:

```
select * from calendar WHERE reserverStartH >=1524222000  AND reserverEndH <=1524240000;
```

is request find it, if find it, we can't reservert it because the human is busy at this timestamp.
But now i would like this request:

```
select * from calendar WHERE reserverStartH >=1524222000  AND reserverEndH <=1524222222;
```

there is not data, if not data I can't reserve it, but it's not possible because in 1524222000 and 1524222222 the human is busy at this time.

How i do for find data ?

the request find data equal we can't insert new timestamps the human is busy
the request not find data equal we can insert new timestamps, the human is free at the moment

Comment: Please speak English, even in the comments.

Comment: I try this request : select * from calendar BETWEEN reserverStartH >=1524222000 AND reserverEndH <=1524230000; => but is bad quest

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, MS SQL? Please tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if two intervals have an intersection.

For example if (a, b) intersects (c,d). Example: if (10,20) has an intersection with (15, 25). It does (15,20).

The logical condition to find if the intersection exists is: `c <= b AND d >= a`

Translating this to your SQL:

```
select * from calendar 
  WHERE 1524222000 <= reserverEndH AND 1524222222 >= reserverStartH;
```

Comment: Facile. De rien.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, apart from accepting it, can you upvote it?